# Test web site is not the same as in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, testing

I am currently working on an asp.net C# project.  It is using MVC 4, Entity Framework, and LINQ.  I am a newbie to all of this.

My client wants me to implement new CSS styles to their website.  I have successfully done this and it looks correct in debug mode(ran on my machine locally localhost:59600/).  But when I got to the test website (which is not local to my machine dev.websitename.com) the CSS style-sheet are not being applied.  Also I do not have FTP or server access.  Is it something in my code or configuration that is causing this problem?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<%= Url.Styles("leaguetime.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<%= Url.Styles("widget-css.css") %>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<%= Url.Styles("dropdownmenu.css") %>" />
```

I have checked to ensure that the CSS files are located in the folder Styles.

I appreciate any and all answers and remember I am a newbie so any simple answer in never too simple. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your CSS files in the root folder of your site on the test server (the same place as the web.config)? Also, is there a reason you are using 'Url.Styles' instead of 'Url.Content'? Also, make sure you are clearing your cache in the browser and are doing a full refresh to get the new CSS files.

Comment: I cleared the cache and that did not solve the issue.  When you say the root folder of your site on the test server.  Do you mean in the Solution Explorer of VS?  Because all that is in the web.config folder is Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config files.  There is also a Web.config file that has code it but I am not sure what it all means. As for the Url.Styles instead of Url.Content I am not sure that is just he way it was done before I started my work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using URL helpers.. might as well make the server paths relative to the root of your site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<%= Url.Content("~/xxx/leaguetime.css") %>" />
```

See: http://amadiere.com/blog/2010/03/4-top-tips-for-portable-asp-net-mvc-apps/